# Search component won't rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a search bar on the frontpage and in the header.

User searches for "Company A" DOM updates to the component for showing Company Info. But when Search Component in Header is used again to search for "Company B". Nothing happens. the URL updates but DOM doesn't react.

Im new to React so i've been using few guides here and there but i've been stuck with this error for a week now.

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-tdd-yo1hb

Comment: And where is the data for company A and B? Where is it coming from? Can you provide a codesandbox implementation?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @SteveTomlin Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-tdd-yo1hb

Comment: Thats not a minimal example, its all your project

Comment: @DennisVash To be honest the entire project is just that at the moment. It is the minimal example. If i remove anything it would break the entire project and then i wouldn't be able to give you any example.

Comment: You asking us to debug your project, such questions has low chance for repsonse, you should ask specific insulated questions in SO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223511/discussion-between-shaydx-and-dennis-vash).